# Cardinality of the set of the regular open sets

Tags: general-topology

is it true that if $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space of weight $\aleph_1$ then it contains exactly $\aleph_1$ regular open sets?

I tried to show that it's true. There exists a basis of $\aleph_1$ regular open sets, therefore every regular open set is an union of elements of this basis. I am trying to write, without success, this regular open sets as a finite union of elements of this basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is at least consistent that the result be false. Let $X=\omega_1+1$ with the usual order topology; $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space of weight $\omega_1$. However, if $A\subseteq\omega$ and $\omega\setminus A$ is infinite, then $A$ is a regular open set in $X$: either $A$ is clopen, or

$$\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}A=\operatorname{int}(A\cup\{\omega\})=A\;.$$

Thus, $X$ has at least $2^\omega=\mathfrak c$ regular open sets, and of course it is consistent that $2^\omega>\omega_1$.

**Added:** The same basic idea can be used to produce an absolute example. Let $X$ be the one-point compactification of a discrete space of cardinality $\omega_1$; $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space of weight $\omega_1$. Let $p$ be the non-isolated point of $X$. If $A\subseteq X\setminus\{p\}$ and $X\setminus A$ is infinite, then either $A$ is finite and therefore clopen, or

$$\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}A=\operatorname{int}(A\cup\{p\})=A\;.$$

Thus, $X$ has $2^{\omega_1}>\omega_1$ regular open sets.